llvm18 ffat-lto-objects undefined vtables
Hi there!
I am porting a project from an old c++ version to a new one, using the newly went out llvm 18 suite.
For this, I would like to enable LTO optimizations, however, due to practical reasons, I am trying to use fat lto (newly added into llvm since the 18 version).
The project I am porting has a huge load of dependencies and so I have to verify the compilation.
However, when I compile with the optimization options (-flto -ffat-lto-objects), I get undefined vtable errors. (undefined symbol: vtable for [class name])
It is systematic, and procs for nearly every single class that inherit and have virtual functions. (the entire list would be way too big to place here, plus since this is code under NDA, I could not even place it there)
What is strange (to me at least) is that, when I remove the fat object support, I have no problem with the vtables.
So, if I compile & link with no option, code compiles and links fine.
if I compile solely with -flto, code compiles and links fine. (same goes for -flto=thin & -funified-lto)
If I add --ffat-lto-objects, suddently lld vomits a ton of errors (always vtable ones).
using unified lto pipeline does not resolve the issue at all
This does not happen in C linkage (I mean, C does not have vtable) and neither from shared library that are self contained.
It's like lld plainly ignores the vtable contained in the deps of my program (whereas the deps is a  shared or static library, the issue is the same, it does not link in the final binary).
hell, in shared library context, it even shows me errors coming from the standard library. (if I link the other libraries as shared libraries and not static ones)
from what I can see in the code, no function is undefined (every single virtual function has a definition, either in a header file or in a source file).
Could it be possible that the fat lto option is not yet mature enough to be brought in a project? or am I missing something (perhaps a flag, or a specificity from fat lto)?
here is a rough example of how the project is defined:
// lib header

class A {
  public:
  A() { /* does stuff */ };
  virtual ~A();
};


// lib source


A::~A() {
  // implementation
}


// bin source

int main()
{
  // whatever
  A variable; // link error pointing to A's constructor


Edit:
after trying a few things, it appears that it is the combination of fat lto and unified lto that brings the errors. having solely fat lto (with thin / full lto) do strictly nothing and do not apply any optimizations, but compile.
Second edit:
Here is a minimal code to reproduce the error:
file1.hpp
class base {
public:
  virtual ~base();
  virtual void fun1();
};

file1.cpp
#include "file1.hpp"

base::~base() {}
void base::fun1() {}

file2.hpp
#include "file1.hpp"

class child : public base {
  public:
  ~child() = default;

  void fun1() override {}
};

main.cpp
#include "file2.hpp"
int main()
{
  child c;
  return 1;
}

Compile with the following command:
clang++-18 main.cpp file1.cpp -o prog -flto -ffat-lto-objects -funified-lto -fuse-ld=lld-18
(replace clang++-18 and lld-18 by the names of your clang + lld version 18 as in previous versions, it compiles. However, since fat lto has been added in llvm18, the flag is probably just ignored)
and you should have this exact link error:
ld.lld-18: error: undefined symbol: vtable for child
>>> referenced by main.cpp
>>>               /tmp/main-0d4e8c.o:(child::child())
>>> the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function (see https://lld.llvm.org/missingkeyfunction)

ld.lld-18: error: undefined symbol: vtable for base
>>> referenced by main.cpp
>>>               /tmp/main-0d4e8c.o:(base::base())
>>> did you mean: typeinfo for base
>>> defined in: /tmp/file1-07950c.o
>>> the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function (see https://lld.llvm.org/missingkeyfunction)
clang++-18: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


i'll edit my message with one

The syntax error here is due to me copying by hand and not copy pasting the code, I'll correct them.
Are you sure you are using llvm version 18? because when I do I have the link error (i'll append the exact error to the og message)

Thanks for adding the error messages.  I am using Clang-18.1.4 that I built from source on Linux.  I do not have an lld-18 program among the build outputs.  I have lld and ld.lld, but neither produces the error you show and the latter links successfully.  Where did you get your Clang?  What is its exact version?  What platform are you running on?  Is lld-18 a symlink, and if so, to what?

No issue, I should've added them at the very beginning. The lld program I have is from the llvm-18 package from debian latest (dunno if that is sid of testing), it is the version 18.1.5 (provided with previous package.) Noteworthy, I did try to simply use a previous lld version (lld 17 and below) and I do not have the link error. This either may be due to a regression in lld, or simply in the fast that lld 17 does not (or may not) support fat-lto (and therefore might ignore the flag).
it is a symlink to ld.lld-18

You should edit those details into the question so future readers don't need to dig into the comments (which can be deleted at any time) to find all of the information.
